# Create synonyms between two tables in different databases Informix

Tags: informix

I have the database `gcd001` that contains multiple tables `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3` which contain data, and a second database `dde002` that contains the same tables `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3` but with no data.

I'm trying to create a script that will create synonyms between the tables of these two databases.  I tried something like:

```
# !/bin/sh
# USAGE : cresyn.sh {dtabase_with_data} {dtabase_no_data} {Table}

dtabase_with_data=$1
dtabase_no_data=$2
Table=$3

dbaccess $1 CREATE SYNONYM $1 FOR $2:$3;

done
```

but it didn't work and I really don't know how to do it.
Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB-Access command doesn't interpret command line arguments like that.  Its usage pattern is:

```
dbaccess [-|database] [-|script]
```

It will add the `.sql` extension to the `script` argument if you don't specify it (so it only executes `.sql` files).  Without the script option, it goes interactive having select the named database.  Without the named database, it goes interactive too, without pre-selecting a database.  The dash for a script name means "read standard input". The dash for a database name means "do not pre-select a database"; presumably the script will select or create the database itself.

You probably want to use:

```
if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "Incorrect arguments.  Usage: $0 db_with db_without tablename" >&2
    exit 1
fi

dbaccess $2 - <<EOF

CREATE SYNONYM $3 FOR $1:$3;

EOF
```

This connects to the 'database without data' (`$2`) and creates a synonym with the same name as the table (`$3`) referencing that table in 'database with data' (`$1`).  You could use the variables you set but didn't use too.

Note that the tables `tab1` .. `tab3` cannot exist in the 'database without data' before you create the synonyms.  Or you have to use an alternative name for the synonyms, such as `syn_tab1`, .. `syn_tab3` (but then your script needs to take arguments for the existing table name and the synonym to be created.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan i'm really new to Informix and your answers are teaching me a lot each time.